# C: error using struct with variable arrays

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct tgPoligono {
    int numero_de_lados;
    CvPoint** cantos;
    float* lados;
    double* angulos;
} *tgPoligono;
```

In a function, I'm using it like this:

```
tgPoligono criar_tgPoligono(CvSeq* poligono){
    int i;
    tgPoligono tg_poligono = (tgPoligono) malloc(sizeof(tgPoligono));

    tg_poligono->numero_de_lados = poligono->total;

    tg_poligono->cantos = (CvPoint**) malloc(tg_poligono->numero_de_lados * sizeof(CvPoint*));
    for(i= 0; i < tg_poligono->numero_de_lados; i++){
        tg_poligono->cantos[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(poligono, i);
    }

    tg_poligono->lados = (float*) malloc(tg_poligono->numero_de_lados * sizeof(float));
    tg_poligono->angulos = (double*) malloc(tg_poligono->numero_de_lados * sizeof(double));
    double* angulos = (double*) malloc(tg_poligono->numero_de_lados * sizeof(double));
    for(i = 0; i < tg_poligono->numero_de_lados; i++){
        CvPoint* pt_0 = tg_poligono->cantos[((i == 0)?(tg_poligono->numero_de_lados - 1):(i - 1))];     //Canto anterior
        CvPoint* pt_1 = tg_poligono->cantos[i];                                                         //Canto atual
        CvPoint* pt_2 = tg_poligono->cantos[(i + 1) % tg_poligono->numero_de_lados];                    //Canto seguinte

        //Calculo a distancia entre dois cantos, o que retorna o comprimento do lado do poligono
        tg_poligono->lados[i] = sqrt(((pt_1->x - pt_2->x)*(pt_1->x - pt_2->x)) + ((pt_1->y - pt_2->y)*(pt_1->y - pt_2->y)));

        //Calculo o cosseno do angulo correspondente ao ponto atualmente avaliado
        tg_poligono->angulos[i] = cosseno(pt_0, pt_2, pt_1);
        angulos[i] = cosseno(pt_0, pt_2, pt_1);
    }

    return tg_poligono;
}
```

Ok, my problem is with the tg_poligono->angulos
tg_poligono->lados works fine but tg_poligono->angulos fails with apparently no reason!

when I use de function in my program (inside a for statment), the code above works for a while and then fails with no message.

If I comment the following lines, the program work fine, with no errors:

```
tg_poligono->angulos = (double*) malloc(tg_poligono->numero_de_lados * sizeof(double));
...
tg_poligono->angulos[i] = cosseno(pt_0, pt_2, pt_1);
```

If you look at my code, you'll see a test that i do:

```
double* angulos = (double*) malloc(tg_poligono->numero_de_lados * sizeof(double));
...
angulos[i] = cosseno(pt_0, pt_2, pt_1);
```

Its the same thing but not using the struct and it works fine.

ps.: I'm using opencv functions on this code, but it's unrelated with the problem.
the function `cosseno(pt_0, pt_2, pt_1)` works fine, I sure of that.
It's a C code, I can't use C++.

Comment: The cast of the return value of `malloc` is not needed and may hide an error. I suggest you remove the casts and let the compiler tell you about the possibly relevant error.

Comment: Did you mean this:
tg_poligono->angulos = malloc(tg_poligono->numero_de_lados * sizeof(double));
I'll try! tnks!

Comment: That's what I mean. **[fizzer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820818/c-error-using-struct-with-variable-arrays/7820953#7820953) is more relevant though**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you want to define your structure, I think:

```
typedef struct _tgPoligono {
    int numero_de_lados;
    CvPoint** cantos;
    float* lados;
    double* angulos;
} tgPoligono;

tgPoligono criar_tgPoligono(CvSeq* poligono){
    int i;
    tgPoligono *tg_poligono = (tgPoligono*) malloc(sizeof(tgPoligono));

etc...
```

Note the removal of the star from the end of your structure definition and typedef. That's what's confusing you I think.

Comment: Cool! Vote up my answer too if you like ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`tgPoligono tg_poligono = (tgPoligono) malloc(sizeof(tgPoligono));`

only allocates space for the pointer.  Use `sizeof(*tgPoligono)`.

Comment: But my struct is like this:
typedef struct tgPoligono { ... } *tgPoligono;
so I don't need this sizeof(*tgPoligono). Right?

Comment: In that case, you allocate memory for a pointer, and not for a structure
Try checking sizeof(tgPoligono) and compare it to sizeof(*tgPoligono)

Comment: Fizzer is right. You are confusing yourself (and others) by hiding a pointer behind a typedef. Creating a variable that differs only in case from its type is not a good habit either. IMHO

Comment: ok, but I'm not having problems with the struct when I don't use the tg_poligono->angulos. You guys think my struct malloc are wrong?

Comment: You don't have a structure. Only a pointer to a structure that points to an object that has a size of sizeof(void*); probably 4 or 8.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand. so a should do this way:

struct tgPoligono {
    int numero_de_lados;
    CvPoint** cantos;
    float* lados;
    double* angulos;
};

tgPoligono* tg_poligono = (*tgPoligono) malloc(sizeof(*tgPoligono));

What's the difference?
Looks the same think to me! =S